# Enable VNC and SSH for user other than `pi`?

Tags: ssh, vnc, raspi-config, user

New to Pi and I am trying to configure my Pi3. I would like to keep the user `pi` intact with the factory password, but still be able to use VNC and SSH without getting the security error message.

I thought I would be able to create a new user, turn off SSH and VNC for `pi` and turn on SSH and VNC for the new user. Unfortunately, I get the repeated error connection refused.

Also when I initially attempted to adjust the user's configuration setting under `Preferences` -> `RaspberryPi Configuration` I got an error message about not being able to create or copy the configuration file. I assume this error was because the user did not have sufficient rights to do so.

My ultimate goal is to leave the user `pi` only accessible locally, while any other user(s) of my choosing can have remote access.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SSH**

SSH is achieved just by creating a new user (useradd) and making a small edit to sshd_config. First lets create the user:

```
useradd UserName
passwd UserName
```

Once the user is created, if you want it to have root access, add it to the sudo group:

```
usermod -aG sudo UserName
```

Next we want to edit the sshd_config as root:

```
sudo -s
nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Once editing sshd, add this line to the configuration:

```
AllowUsers UserName
```

Press CTRL+X, y to accept the changes, enter to confirm the title of the file (overwriting).

Now for this configuration to take place, we need to restart SSH:

```
service ssh restart
```

Here is a great guide on VNC, and although it's about CentOS, the commands are the same :

https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/VNC-Server#head-2af7c99dd1f5f5b6c8bd1d4b4ada5e4823184064

Comment: This is the right way to do it, but I'm a little bummed that the integrated preferences panel won't allow you to control settings like this per user. Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

I just updated my pi to raspian stretch and the link for the vnc config does not reflect the changes in that the following directory doesnt exit /etc/sysconfig/.....: https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/VNC-Server#head-2af7c99dd1f5f5b6c8bd1d4b4ada5e4823184064

I just opened VNC on my pi, clicked options and added the relevant user.